# Android Gif animation slow animate rate

Tags: android, animation, gif, android-glide

> Hi all i have a requirement in  my project.
>
> i need to show a gif file after completing of that gif animation i need to show other gif file
>
> ex:  **my first gif animation time is 10second so after completing 10 second i need to play other gif with 5seconds and so on**.
>
> I am able to get gif animation time but gif rendering took to much time to play gif if my gif animation time is 10sec then it took around 15-20sec to 
>   play entire gif
>
> I am using **Glide** Library
>
> i get gif duration from getGifDurationTime and after that onResourceReady i scheduled a runnable to finishTime 
>           but my runnable execute before gif animate finish complete.actually runnable is execute at right time but system play gif very slow rate

```
public static int getGifDurationTime(File file){
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        int duration = movie.duration();
        return duration;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    int duration = movie.duration();
    return 0;
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //code to show next gif  
    }
};

File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), GiftManager.FOLDER_NAME+"/"+fileName);
int finishTime = getGifDurationTime(file);

GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(giftImageView) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> animation) {
        super.onResourceReady(resource, animation);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, finishTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
        super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
    }
};

Glide.with(context).load(file).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Comment: were you able to solve this problem @Vishal Gaur ??

Comment: @DRYBeliever try this https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Comment: :P Dude... using the same ... did you find any work around in Glide ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asGif()
                    .load(R.drawable.source)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                    .into(ImageViewObject);
```